# FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.empowered.healo, PID: 28143 io.reactivex.exceptions.CompositeException: 2 exceptions occurred.?

Tags: java, android, android-savedstate

I am developing a new app  and  I am getting two exceptions below.

I have been trying to solve almost a day but I cant find any solution to this

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after
>   onSaveInstanceState
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:2080)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:837)
>           at ru.terrakok.cicerone.android.SupportFragmentNavigator.backToRoot(SupportFragmentNavigator.java:148)
>           at ru.terrakok.cicerone.android.SupportFragmentNavigator.applyCommand(SupportFragmentNavigator.java:128)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   ru.terrakok.cicerone.android.SupportAppNavigator.applyCommand(SupportAppNavigator.java:77)
>           at ru.terrakok.cicerone.CommandBuffer.executeCommand(CommandBuffer.java:43)
>           at ru.terrakok.cicerone.BaseRouter.executeCommand(BaseRouter.java:31)
>           at ru.terrakok.cicerone.Router.newRootScreen(Router.java:125) W/System.err:     at
>   com.empowered.healo.ui.activities.main.MainActivity.moveToScreen(MainActivity.kt:400)
>           at com.empowered.healo.ui.activities.main.MainPresenter$getSession$1.accept(MainPresenter.kt:80)
>           at com.empowered.healo.ui.activities.main.MainPresenter$getSession$1.accept(MainPresenter.kt:25)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onNext(LambdaObserver.java:60)
>           at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.drainNormal(ObservableObserveOn.java:200)
>           at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.run(ObservableObserveOn.java:252)
>           at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:109)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
>   W/System.err: io.reactivex.exceptions.CompositeException: 2 exceptions
>   occurred. 
>           at io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onError(LambdaObserver.java:77)
>           at io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onNext(LambdaObserver.java:64)
>           at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.drainNormal(ObservableObserveOn.java:200)
>           at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.run(ObservableObserveOn.java:252)
>           at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:109)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
>   W/System.err:   ComposedException 1 :
>         java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:2080)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:837)
>           at ru.terrakok.cicerone.android.SupportFragmentNavigator.backToRoot(SupportFragmentNavigator.java:148)
>           at ru.terrakok.cicerone.android.SupportFragmentNavigator.applyCommand(SupportFragmentNavigator.java:128)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   ru.terrakok.cicerone.android.SupportAppNavigator.applyCommand(SupportAppNavigator.java:77)
>           at ru.terrakok.cicerone.CommandBuffer.executeCommand(CommandBuffer.java:43)
>           at ru.terrakok.cicerone.BaseRouter.executeCommand(BaseRouter.java:31)
>           at ru.terrakok.cicerone.Router.newRootScreen(Router.java:125)
>           at com.empowered.healo.ui.activities.main.MainActivity.moveToScreen(MainActivity.kt:400)
>           at com.empowered.healo.ui.activities.main.MainPresenter$getSession$1.accept(MainPresenter.kt:80)
>           at com.empowered.healo.ui.activities.main.MainPresenter$getSession$1.accept(MainPresenter.kt:25)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onNext(LambdaObserver.java:60)
>           at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.drainNormal(ObservableObserveOn.java:200)
>           at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.run(ObservableObserveOn.java:252)
>           at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:109)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
>         ComposedException 2 :
>         java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState W/System.err:     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:2080)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:837)
>           at ru.terrakok.cicerone.android.SupportFragmentNavigator.backToRoot(SupportFragmentNavigator.java:148)
>           at ru.terrakok.cicerone.android.SupportFragmentNavigator.applyCommand(SupportFragmentNavigator.java:128)
>           at ru.terrakok.cicerone.android.SupportAppNavigator.applyCommand(SupportAppNavigator.java:77)
>           at ru.terrakok.cicerone.CommandBuffer.executeCommand(CommandBuffer.java:43)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   ru.terrakok.cicerone.BaseRouter.executeCommand(BaseRouter.java:31)
>           at ru.terrakok.cicerone.Router.newRootScreen(Router.java:125)
>           at com.empowered.healo.ui.activities.main.MainActivity.moveToScreen(MainActivity.kt:400)
>           at com.empowered.healo.ui.activities.main.MainPresenter$getSession$2.accept(MainPresenter.kt:85)
>           at com.empowered.healo.ui.activities.main.MainPresenter$getSession$2.accept(MainPresenter.kt:25)
>           at io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onError(LambdaObserver.java:74)
>           at io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onNext(LambdaObserver.java:64)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.drainNormal(ObservableObserveOn.java:200)
>           at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.run(ObservableObserveOn.java:252)
>           at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:109)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
>   I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false I/System.out:
>   (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.empowered.healo, PID: 28143
>       io.reactivex.exceptions.CompositeException: 2 exceptions occurred. 
>           at io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onError(LambdaObserver.java:77)
>           at io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onNext(LambdaObserver.java:64)
>           at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.drainNormal(ObservableObserveOn.java:200)
>           at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.run(ObservableObserveOn.java:252)
>           at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:109)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
>         ComposedException 1 :
>         java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:2080)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:837)
>           at ru.terrakok.cicerone.android.SupportFragmentNavigator.backToRoot(SupportFragmentNavigator.java:148)
>           at ru.terrakok.cicerone.android.SupportFragmentNavigator.applyCommand(SupportFragmentNavigator.java:128)
>           at ru.terrakok.cicerone.android.SupportAppNavigator.applyCommand(SupportAppNavigator.java:77)
>           at ru.terrakok.cicerone.CommandBuffer.executeCommand(CommandBuffer.java:43)
>           at ru.terrakok.cicerone.BaseRouter.executeCommand(BaseRouter.java:31)
>           at ru.terrakok.cicerone.Router.newRootScreen(Router.java:125)
>           at com.empowered.healo.ui.activities.main.MainActivity.moveToScreen(MainActivity.kt:400)
>           at com.empowered.healo.ui.activities.main.MainPresenter$getSession$1.accept(MainPresenter.kt:80)
>           at com.empowered.healo.ui.activities.main.MainPresenter$getSession$1.accept(MainPresenter.kt:25)
>           at io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onNext(LambdaObserver.java:60)
>           at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.drainNormal(ObservableObserveOn.java:200)
>           at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.run(ObservableObserveOn.java:252)
>           at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:109)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
>        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:2080)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:837)
>           at ru.terrakok.cicerone.android.SupportFragmentNavigator.backToRoot(SupportFragmentNavigator.java:148)
>           at ru.terrakok.cicerone.android.SupportFragmentNavigator.applyCommand(SupportFragmentNavigator.java:128)
>           at ru.terrakok.cicerone.android.SupportAppNavigator.applyCommand(SupportAppNavigator.java:77)
>           at ru.terrakok.cicerone.CommandBuffer.executeCommand(CommandBuffer.java:43)
>           at ru.terrakok.cicerone.BaseRouter.executeCommand(BaseRouter.java:31)
>           at ru.terrakok.cicerone.Router.newRootScreen(Router.java:125)
>           at com.empowered.healo.ui.activities.main.MainActivity.moveToScreen(MainActivity.kt:400)
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.empowered.healo.ui.activities.main.MainPresenter$getSession$2.accept(MainPresenter.kt:85)
>           at com.empowered.healo.ui.activities.main.MainPresenter$getSession$2.accept(MainPresenter.kt:25)
>           at io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onError(LambdaObserver.java:74)
>           at io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onNext(LambdaObserver.java:64)
>           at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.drainNormal(ObservableObserveOn.java:200)
>           at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.run(ObservableObserveOn.java:252)
>           at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:109)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
>         ComposedException 2 :
>         java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:2080)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:837)
>           at ru.terrakok.cicerone.android.SupportFragmentNavigator.backToRoot(SupportFragmentNavigator.java:148)
>           at ru.terrakok.cicerone.android.SupportFragmentNavigator.applyCommand(SupportFragmentNavigator.java:128)
>           at ru.terrakok.cicerone.android.SupportAppNavigator.applyCommand(SupportAppNavigator.java:77)
>           at ru.terrakok.cicerone.CommandBuffer.executeCommand(CommandBuffer.java:43)
>           at ru.terrakok.cicerone.BaseRouter.executeCommand(BaseRouter.java:31)
>           at ru.terrakok.cicerone.Router.newRootScreen(Router.java:125)
>           at com.empowered.healo.ui.activities.main.MainActivity.moveToScreen(MainActivity.kt:400)
>           at com.empowered.healo.ui.activities.main.MainPresenter$getSession$2.accept(MainPresenter.kt:85)
>           at com.empowered.healo.ui.activities.main.MainPresenter$getSession$2.accept(MainPresenter.kt:25)
>           at io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onError(LambdaObserver.java:74)
>           at io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onNext(LambdaObserver.java:64)
>           at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.drainNormal(ObservableObserveOn.java:200)
>           at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.run(ObservableObserveOn.java:252)
>           at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:109)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)